# Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'elForm' in undefined" when used with type "datetime"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, datepicker, element-ui

I am trying to bring up a datepicker with time options from Element UI.
I am facing this error from within ElementUI component. It works if `type` option is set as `date` and throws an error on `datetime`.
Here is my code and error.

```js
import { cloneDeep } from 'lodash';

export default {
  name: 'actions',
  components: {},
  props: {
    data: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => ({}),
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      indentData: {
        reported_at: '',
      },
    };
  },
  computed: {
    validToPickerOptions() {
      const endOfDay = new Date(new Date().setHours(23, 59, 59, 999));
      return {
        disabledDate(time) {
          return (time >= endOfDay);
        },
      };
    },
  },
  methods: {
    reportMarkReported() {
      console.log('this.indentData', this.indentData);
      this.$emit('save-report-release', this.indentData);
    },
  },
  created() {
    this.indentData = cloneDeep(this.data);
  },
};
```

```html
<template>
  <div>
  <div class="action">
    <button @click="reportMarkReported">
      Submit
    </button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <el-date-picker
      v-model="indentData.reported_at"
      type="datetime"
      format="dd MMM 'yy hh:mm A"
      placeholder="Pick a Date"
      size="small"
    />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Here is the error I am facing on click on element

```
vue.esm.js?b66f:1741 TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'elForm' in undefined
    at resolveInject (vue.esm.js?efeb:4649:1)
    at initInjections (vue.esm.js?efeb:4619:1)
    at Vue._init (vue.esm.js?efeb:4710:1)
    at new VueComponent (vue.esm.js?efeb:5836:1)
    at createComponentInstanceForVnode (vue.esm.js?b66f:4310:1)
    at init (vue.esm.js?b66f:4131:1)
    at createComponent (vue.esm.js?b66f:5608:1)
    at createElm (vue.esm.js?b66f:5555:1)
    at createChildren (vue.esm.js?b66f:5682:1)
    at createElm (vue.esm.js?b66f:5584:1)
```

```
vue.esm.js?b66f:591 [Vue warn]: Error in nextTick: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '$el')"
```

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '$el')
    at Vue.eval (element-ui.common.js?bc95:18396:1)
    at Array.eval (vue.esm.js?b66f:1837:1)
    at flushCallbacks (vue.esm.js?b66f:1758:1)
```

Comment: Current Element UI version is `2.10.1`

Answer (score 0):

Updating my element-ui version to `2.15` worked out. This was fixed in the recent version